# How will Arrays.asList() work in this scenario?

Tags: java, arrays

```
Long[] myArr = new Long[size];

// Code to store values in myArr

List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<Long>();

// Code to store values in myList

myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArr));
myArr = null;
```

Documentation of `Arrays.asList()` says that the list returned is backed by the original array, and changes to the elements in the list will "write through" to the original array. I'd like to know if set `myArr` to `null`, will it remove the list elements created through `myArr` ?
I'm guessing that it won't since I'm only setting the reference variable to `null` and the original array is still there in memory referred by `myList`. Am I right in thinking so ?

Comment: Changing the value of `myArr` doesn't do *anything* to the object it previously referred to, no.

Comment: And since `myList` is still referring to the object, garbage collector will not clear it right ?

Comment: No, `myList` doesn't refer to the previous list, because `addAll` has just *iterated* over the list, and added each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `List.addAll()` method will add all of the elements to its internal data structure (in this case an array). No mutation to the `myArr` would have any impact to the values in `myList`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

`myArr = null` changes the reference, not the array itself.